# Get windows username without using activex object

Tags: javascript, asp.net, windows, iis, activexobject

is it possible to get clients windows username in asp.net hosted in remote server without using activex object ?

i have used following code

```
        Response.Write("HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name  " & HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name)
        Response.Write("<br/>")
        Response.Write("HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated " & HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        Response.Write("<br/>")
        Response.Write("HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name " & HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)
        Response.Write("<br/>")
        Response.Write("System.Environment.UserName " & System.Environment.UserName)
        Response.Write("<br/>")
        Response.Write("Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name() " & System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name())
        Response.Write("<br/>")
```

but it is always giving me server user name not the clients username .

Comment: How is your virtual directory/application configured?

Comment: It's possible only if you're using Windows Authentication.

Comment: It's possible but the way in which you access this info is different in every browser ( if it even exisits). For instance Mozilla FireFox you use [nsIEnvironment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIEnvironment). So your javascript would first detect the browser then access the windows user name accordingly . Also if your using C# you could use [WAFFLE](http://dblock.github.io/waffle/)  [Source](https://github.com/dblock/waffle)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti using windows authentication only works on intranet but not in internet isnt it ?

Comment: Yes, only in Intranet because accessing that information with JavaScript cannot from an untrusted site can be a security issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use ServerVariables

```
string Hostname=Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"];
string Username=Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_USER"];
```

Comment: _"[REMOTE_USER] The name of the user as it is **derived from the authorization header sent by the client**, before the user name is mapped to a Windows account. If you have an authentication filter installed on your Web server that maps incoming users to accounts, use LOGON_USER to view the mapped user name."_

Answer (score -2):

this line will work if you are using "Windows Authentication"

```
Response.Write("HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name " & HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)
```

ref: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user(v=vs.110).aspx)